# MongoDB: how to query with a specific rule for a specific element in $in?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Honestly I doubt that it is possible but just giving a shot here.

Here's an example of DB records

```
{
    type: 'fruit',
    name: 'apple',
    quantity: 3
}
{
    type: 'fruit',
    name: 'orange',
    quantity: 10
}
{
    type: 'vegetable',
    name: 'tomato',
    quantity: 4
}
{
    type: 'meat',
    name: 'beef',
    quantity: 2
}
```

then here's the query

```
{type: { $in: ['fruit', 'vegetable', 'meat']}}
```

So this will return all of the records in collection 'apple', 'orange', 'tomato', 'beef'.

I would like to query 'fruit', 'vegetable', 'meat' and also the records that have quantities more than 5 for `'fruit' only but not others`.
So the result will be

```
orange, tomato, beef
```

Not sure my explanation makes sense but is this a possible query? or I should go query twice?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Could you tell whether `orange` should be in the expected result set - I;m asking because in the example provided it has `quantity = 5`. Thx in adv.

Comment: Oh yes you are right. The orange should be more than 5!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
{ 
    $or: [
        { type: { $in: ['vegetable', 'meat'] } },
        { type: { $in: ['fruit'] }, quantity: { $gt: 5 } } 
    ]
}
```

I hope that helps.